# function rfrsh() not working when put on an external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

my function "rfrsh()" is working when it is inside the html file but when i put it on an external javascript file, it is now working anymore. here is my code

```js
/* JavaScript */

$(document).ready(function() {
     
    function rfrsh() {
        $("iframe").each(function() { 
            var src= $(this).attr('src');
            $(this).attr('src',src);  
        });
    }        
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div id="circtraff" class="tab-pane active">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="circtraff_tabs">
    <li><a href="#circtraff_realtime" data-toggle="tab" onClick="rfrsh()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Real-time Traffic</a></li>
    <li><a href="#circtraff_last24" data-toggle="tab" onClick="rfrsh()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Last 24 Hours</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

all other js functions are working except for the refresh function.

Comment: You did not provide [MCVE] but most likely you load JS after HTML elements are initialized and hence fail to find that function... Looking at browser console should confirm that... Using JQuery to subscribe to listen to events on controls consistently would likely solve it (again not possible to answer without [MCVE]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're scoping the `rfrsh` function to be local to the `$(document).ready()` function. To make it available to your HTML `onClick` event, define it in the `window` namespace, like so:

`window.rfrsh = function() {
         /* ... */
    };`